# Scheduling Job in .NET using Threads & Timers

Tags: .net, multithreading, timer, task

This is the requirement.

I have job/task which takes one parameter as input and performs some function.

I need to execute the method DoWork at different schedule timings with different input parameter. Lets say,
at 1 PM, DoWork has to be triggered with input1.
at 1.30 PM, DoWork has to be triggered with input2.
at 3 PM, DoWork has to be triggered with input3.
....

Which is the best way to do this??
- Using System.Timer
- Using System.Threading.Timer
- Using TaskFactory & TaskScheduler

Whatever I tried so far, first of all there is a Windows Service:

```
public partial class MainJobExecWS : ServiceBase
{
    private Timer taskTimer;

    public MainJobExecWS()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // Define Timer for MainJob
        TimeSpan dueTime = // define starting time of timer;
        TimeSpan repeatingPeriod = // define repeating interval of timer;
        MainJob jm = new MainJob();
        TimerCallback tcb = jm.executeMainJob;
        taskTimer = new Timer(tcb, null, dueTime, repeatingPeriod);   
        base.OnStart(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (taskTimer != null)
        {
            taskTimer.Dispose();
        }
        base.OnStop();
    }
}
```

Definition for the Main Job:

```
class MainJob
    {
        public void executeMainJob(object state)
        {
            // Main Job Definition
        }

        private void scheduleChildJob()
        {
            String childJobInput = "abc"; // How to pass this input to the child job????
            TimeSpan execTimeSpan = // define the timespan for triggering child job;
            ChildJobDef chdJob = new ChildJobDef();
            TimerCallback tcb = chdJob.executeChildJob; 
            Timer timer = new Timer(tcb, null, execTimeSpan, ?); // How to specify that the child job should be triggered only once??
        }
    }
```

And finally the definition for Child Job Definition:

```
class ChildJobDef
{
    public void executeChildJob(object state)
    {
        // How to get the input sent to this job???
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've attempted so far?  What is your initial design?

Comment: My Initial Design was entirely based on Quartz.NET but for some internal reasons I had to move out from Quartz.

Comment: I've edited my question to display the main approach.

Answer (score 1):

I find the Reactive Extensions handle these scenarios best, as their `IScheduler` interface lets you to schedule actions to run at a specific, absolute time (as opposed to specifying a relative delay).  Their schedulers are fairly robust, and will compensate for clock drift, changes to system time, etc.

Using them is easy:

```
DateTimeOffset startTime = /* determine start time */;
Scheduler.Default.Schedule(startTime, () => RunTask1());
```

Comment: but what if `Now` is today at 2:00PM?

Comment: Good point.  I edited the answer to avoid my "dumb example" date calculation from being taken literally.

Comment: I have a whole scheduling framework at work built on top of Rx and NCrontab. Highly recommend this route.

Comment: Hi Guyz.. Thanks for your replies.. I'm in a position not to use any scheduling framework but to use native .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

I was bored so I threw together a demo of using `System.Timers.Timer` to schedule a task to run at the next instance of a specific time:

```
public class ScheduledTask<T>
{
    private T _parameter;
    private Action<T> _action;
    private Timer _timer;

    public ScheduledTask( T parameter, Action<T> action, int hour, int minute, int second )
    {
        Debug.Assert( null != parameter && null != action, "Arg(s) == null" );

        _parameter = parameter;
        _action = action;

        _timer = new Timer( GetIntervalForTimeOfDay( hour, minute, second ) )
        {
            AutoReset = false
        };

        _timer.Elapsed += ( sender, e ) =>
            {
                if( null != TaskStarted )
                {
                    TaskStarted( this, new DateTimeEventArgs( DateTime.Now ) );
                }

                action( _parameter );

                if( null != TaskCompleted )
                {
                    TaskCompleted( this, new DateTimeEventArgs( DateTime.Now ) );
                }
            };

        _timer.Start();
    }

    public static double GetIntervalForTimeOfDay( int hour, int minute, int second )
    {
        Debug.Assert( hour <= 23 && hour >= 0 && minute <= 59 && minute >= 0 && second <= 59 && second >= 0, "Parameter(s) out of range" );

        var now = DateTime.Now;

        var interval = ( new DateTime( now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, hour, minute, second ) )
            .Subtract( now )
            .TotalMilliseconds;

        if( 0.0 > interval )
        {
            interval += 24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 1000.0; // hours in day * minutes in hour * seconds in minute * milliseconds in minute
        }

        return interval;
    }

    public event EventHandler<DateTimeEventArgs> TaskStarted;
    public event EventHandler<DateTimeEventArgs> TaskCompleted;
}

public class DateTimeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; private set; }

    public DateTimeEventArgs( DateTime dt )
    {
        DateTime = dt;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "App started: {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now );

        var st1 = new ScheduledTask<int>( 1, i =>
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
                Console.WriteLine( "{0}: {1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", i, DateTime.Now );
            }, 15, 30, 0 ); // 3:30:00 PM

        st1.TaskStarted += ( sender, e ) => Console.WriteLine( "1 started: {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now );
        st1.TaskCompleted += ( sender, e ) => Console.WriteLine( "1 completed: {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now );

        var st2 = new ScheduledTask<int>( 2, i =>
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
                Console.WriteLine( "{0}: {1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", i, DateTime.Now );
            }, 15, 51, 7 ); // 3:51:07 PM

        st2.TaskStarted += ( sender, e ) => Console.WriteLine( "2 started: {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now );
        st2.TaskCompleted += ( sender, e ) => Console.WriteLine( "2 completed: {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now );


        Console.WriteLine( "App thread paused: {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now );

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Moho.. I'm new to .NET so it'll take some time for me to understand your approach.

Comment: but one major point in my requirement is, there is a Main Job that is scheduled to run every 5 mins using timer. this Main Job (during its individual execution) will schedule the child jobs (stated in my original question).. so this Main Job shud not wait till the Child Jobs are scheduled and executed.. how to do this???